# Convert IP address in String format to Hex in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy, hex, ip-address

I want to convert an IP address in String format, "1.2.3.4", to this hex format: 0x01020304.

When using InetAddress.getByName, it also adds Address-Type bits, which I don't want.

Is there any other method I can use for this?

Otherwise, I thought about manually tokenize the String as follows:

```
def digitsList = "1.2.3.4".tokenize('.');
```

But then I don't know how to proceed from there to lay the digits on the desired hex format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
String hex = '0x' + '128.234.1.1'.tokenize( '.' )*.toInteger()
                                                  .asType( byte[] )
                                                  .encodeHex()
```

An alternative that should work for all versions of Groovy would be:

```
String hex = '0x' + '128.234.1.1'.tokenize( '.' ).collect {
  String.format( '%02x', it.toInteger() )
}.join()
```

Comment: When trying that, I get the following error:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [B.
encodeHex() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: @ferguior Are you using Groovy pre v1.8.6 (Feb 2012)?

Comment: The alternative worked fine. Indeed, I am not using the latest Groovy version.
Thanks!